# Best Language for dynamically watermarking videos?

Tags: video, video-processing

I'm looking to dynamically add watermarks to a video on a website. What, in your opinion, is the best language and library to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using ffmpeg (from command line or using one of its API such as [ffmpeg-php](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/)) with the [watermark](http://www.linuxjournal.com/video/add-watermark-video-ffmpeg) or [drawtext](http://goinggnu.wordpress.com/2007/05/07/watermark-videos-with-ffmpeg/) vhook component, depending of what you want to add (a logo or a simple text).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have a couple choices.

Both Flash and Silverlight should allow you to create a separate layer and have your watermark displayed.

I'm not sure if there is a way to do this with mpeg/qt videos.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/ is better to dynamically add watermarks to a video on your website.